# Issue with AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'page'

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, attr

I don't know why this error came when I ran my code. Please help me.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/Stocks/Classes/Hamed/Option Pricing/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url2)
page2=driver.page.source
tables2=pd.read_html(page2)
```

Comment: page_source, not page.source

Comment: Thanks. It was a stupid mistake.